# Issue when Editing/Updating row values of jqxGrid bound with a Knockout observable array, replace observable object edited with a javascript object

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, ko.observablearray, jqxgrid, jqwidget

How prevent this behavior of changing object in observableArray when user modified or edit a row in jqxGrid.
I have a knockout observable array of Users, where each User have all is properties as observables,then I bound that observable array to a jqxGrid (from jqWidgets). And when I updated in the grid a User value, then in the observable array that item is replaced with an object containing the values of the observables of this User.

Below is my code:
**HTML Section:**

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="jqxGrid"
        data-bind="jqxGrid: {
        source: Users,
        editable: true,
        width: '100%',
        selectionmode: 'singlecell',
        columns: [
            { text: 'IsChecked', columntype: 'checkbox', dataField: 'IsChecked', width: '10%' },
            { text: 'FirstName', dataField: 'FirstName', width: '40%', editable: false, sortable: true },
            { text: 'LastName', dataField: 'LastName', width: '40%', editable: true, sortable: true }
        ]
    }">
    </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript code:**  (Creation of Users array, ViewModel initialization, ko.applyBindings invocation.)

```
function UserModel (user) {
    
    var self = this;

    self.IsChecked = ko.observable(false); // later I will use this proerty in other place
    self.Username = ko.observable(user.Username);
    self.FirstName = ko.observable(user.FirstName);
    self.LastName = ko.observable(user.LastName);

    // I want to put a isDirty property here
}

var initialUsers = [
    new UserModel({ Username: 'JohnMicrosoft', FirstName: 'John', LastName: 'Microsoft' }),
    new UserModel({ Username: 'JohnGoogle', FirstName: 'John', LastName: 'Google' }),
    new UserModel({ Username: 'JohnApple', FirstName: 'John', LastName: 'Apple' }),

];

var viewModel = null;
$(document).ready(function () {

    viewModel = new UserViewModel(initialUsers);
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

});

function UserViewModel(initialUsers) {
    var self = this;

    self.Users = ko.observableArray(initialUsers);
};
```

This images show how the values changes after I click in the first row in IsChecked checkbox.

[image: See Users observable array, item 0 values are observables]

Result of clicking IsChecked checbox of first row in jqxGrid
[image]

The problem is that I want to add some functions to UserModel object and I want to keep the observables because I want to use them in other part of my page. I have een working in this for days and dont know what to do any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I made something similar. Maybe it can help you:

```
    var Goods = function (obj) {
    var name = ko.observable(obj.name);
    var sales = ko.observable(obj.sales);
    var price = ko.observable(obj.price);
    var extra = ko.observable(obj.extra);
    var id = ko.observable(obj.id);

    name.subscribe(alert('name changed'));

    return {
        name: name,
        sales: sales,
        price: price,
        extra: extra,
        id: id
    };
};

var items = ko.observableArray([
new Goods({ id:  1, name: "Furious Lizard", sales: 152, price: 25.00 }),
new Goods({ id:  2, name: "Indifferent Monkey", sales: 1, price: 99.95 }),
]);

var source = {
localdata: items,
datatype: 'local'
};
```

In the view I have only this: 
`<div id="jqxgrid"></div>`

In the document ready function I have initialized the grid:

`$("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid({
    source: source,
    ....
});`